# I want to make a search bar of omdb but I'm stuck on something

Tags: javascript

I want to make it instant react to search the movie, but it didn't. It only change when I change the value of input in html file. It didn't show when I type the word in input box in website

```
async function getapi() {
   const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchbar");
    searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
       const value = e.target.value;
       searchInput.setAttribute("value", `${value}`);
     console.log(value);
   });
  const response = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchInput.value}&apikey=e4bbcb9c`
  );
    var data = await response.json();
    let movie = Object(data);
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    para.innerText = movie.Search[i].Title;
    document.body.appendChild(para);
    }
}

getapi()
```

I want it instant show the result when I type the word in input box.

Comment: Perhaps a typo?  Your code is very inconsistently indented, by which you may be confusing yourself regarding which operations are part of which code blocks.  The code block responding to the `input` event does nothing but update its own value (which doesn't make sense) and log the value to the console.  The `fetch` operation is not part of that code block.

Comment: Update: Since you keep deleting your comments, I'm going to stop replying.  You are encouraged to correct the problem that's been pointed out in the code.

Comment: Is this logic wrong from the beginning? i just want to change the s of the omdbapi when i type on the input bar.Is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your `eventlistener` to be outside `getapi()`, then call the method with the `searchInput` value as a parameter.

I don't know, but I don't fancy calling an API for every single keypress, but that's just me. Especially if the user is deleting a character in the input.

Also, the script will crash if you get less than three responses.

```js
const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchbar");
const response = document.getElementById("response");

searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  
  getapi(value)
});

async function getapi(searchStr) {
  const API_KEY = 'e4bbcb9c';

  if (searchStr.length) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchInput.value}&apikey=${API_KEY}`);
    var data = await response.json();
    
    let movie = Object(data);
    
    response.innerHTML = '';
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const para = document.createElement("p");
      para.innerText = movie.Search[i].Title;
      document.body.appendChild(para);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchbar" placeholder="Search omdb" />

<section id="response"></section>
```

Comment: oh i made a silly mistake thank you so much .